# Can I emulate/provoke failure to copy to clipboard from JS in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, copy-paste

I have a web page with some JavaScript code that copies stuff to the clipboard similar to what this demo does: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/javascript-copy-clipboard.php

My code is something like this:

```
// Within a listener that is triggered by a click on some button:
var copiedText = "...something";

navigator.clipboard.writeText(copiedText).then(
            function() {
                console.log("Succesfully copied");
            },
            function() {
                console.log("FAILED to copy!!!!!!");
            }
);
```

This works fine, but it always succeeds. I need to test that the behavior is correct when copying fails for whatever reason.

How can I cause the copy to fail on purpose so that I can test the behavior of my code in that situation?

I never get a prompt asking me permission to write to the clipboard.

In Chrome, I have tried going to the site settings for the site, and under "Clipboard" selecting "Block", but it does nothing (I guess that's only for *reading* from the clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just provide an invalid argument which will throw an exception during the stringification algorithm:

> Note that this demo will work in your own page, but the success case won't work in the Stack Overflow code snippet iframe sandbox (where there is no clipboard permission).

```js
function copyThenLog (input) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(input).then(
    () => console.log({success: true}),
    (ex) => {
      console.log({success: false});
      console.error(ex);
    },
  );
}

document.querySelector('.success').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const input = 'hello world';
  copyThenLog(input);
});

document.querySelector('.fail').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const input = {
    toString () {
      throw new Error('Oops');
    }
  };

  copyThenLog(input);
});
```

```html
<div class="success">Click me to succeed</div>
<div class="fail">Click me to fail</div>
```